# Dividing a Time Field using mySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a single time-series table with some data, but the time-stamp is occasionally off. To check the timestamp, we have been manually defining sunrise and sunset to get an estimate of solar noon using the PAR (Photosynthetically Active Radiation) values - PAR tells how much light is coming in - to determine daybreak and nightfall, then extrapolate solar noon at the midpoint between the two. We decided to declare that the record where PAR rises above 1.9, usually about 7AM, is daybreak, and the record where PAR is equal to or less than 1.9 is considered nightfall.

I've selected the PAR values above 1.9, and then find the min and max time values for each day using a GROUP BY, and this works:

SELECT datePart, MIN(timePart) AS sunrise, 
    MAX(timePart) as sunset, 
    TIMEDIFF(MAX(timePart), 
    MIN(timePart)) AS dayHours FROM 
    `Imnavait101119_110225` 
    WHERE `PAR_2029410_uE` >1.9 
    GROUP BY datePart

I get this (yes, it's correct, it's an arctic site).

```
    datePart    sunrise sunset          dayHours    dayHoursHalf
    07/09/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/10/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/11/2010  0:07:00 23:22:00    23:15:00    NULL
    07/12/2010  1:37:00 23:52:00    22:15:00    NULL
    07/13/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/14/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/15/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/16/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/17/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/18/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/19/2010  0:22:00 23:52:00    23:30:00    NULL
    07/20/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
    07/21/2010  0:07:00 23:52:00    23:45:00    NULL
```

Now that I have the TIMEDIFF value, I want to divide this value by 2 to add to sunrise to get solar noon. I created a column to hold the value, but can't seem to figure out how to get it. I've  been able to divide by 2 or multiply by 0.50, but get very weird results, usually along these lines

```
SELECT  @dayHoursHalf := (dayHours * 0.50) as dayHoursHalf
```

FROM Imnavait101119_110225_TimestampCheck

and I get this:

```
dayHoursHalf
117250
117250
115750
110750
117250
117250
117250
117250
117250
117250
116500
117250
117250
117250
```

I don't even know where to start - these numbers make no sense to me, and I can't find anything about how to code a query for a fractional time value.

Many thanks to all responders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I erroneously calculated "mid day" instead of just half of `dayHours`, this query will do what you really wanted :)

```
UPDATE Imnavait101119_110225_TimestampCheck 
   SET dayHoursHalf = SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(dayHours)/2);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c086/1).

---

Original:

This query instead calculates the time of "mid day", right between sunrise and sunset;

```sql
UPDATE Imnavait101119_110225_TimestampCheck 
  SET dayHoursHalf = SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(`sunrise`)  + 
                                 TIME_TO_SEC(dayHours)/2);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2b86/1).

(note that SQLfiddle shows dummy dates for time values for some reason :) )

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Joachim. This is a very concise and elegant query, but it doesn't seem to give me an accurate halving of the dayHours. Here is one of the results of my query. It may be a problem in my original data. 
dayHours = 18:45:00  dayHoursHalf=12:44:30

Comment: @velvetmonster oh, I thought dayhourshalf was supposed to be set to the time right between sunrise and sunset... updating...

Comment: Perfect!!!! The midday query is also quite useful - I didn't realize it was the midday value - and much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 11.7250 x 2 = 23.45, whih is the value of your "Day hours". 
If i got this right, you need to divide the time by 2, so first of all I think that is better to substr() your value and get 23 and 45. Than you can get the right time.

Comment: Thank you for this  information, Jackerbil, it will probably be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If understand correctly you can do it like this to select your values

```sql
SELECT q.*, 
       ADDTIME(sunrise, SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(dayHours) / 2)) dayHoursHalf 
FROM
(
  SELECT datePart, 
         MIN(timePart) sunrise, 
         MAX(timePart) sunset, 
         TIMEDIFF(MAX(timePart), MIN(timePart)) dayHours 
    FROM Imnavait101119_110225 
   WHERE PAR_2029410_uE > 1.9 
   GROUP BY datePart
) q
```

Sample output:

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| datePart   | sunrise  | sunset   | dayHours | dayHoursHalf  |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| 2010-07-09 | 00:07:00 | 23:52:00 | 23:45:00 | 11:59:30.0000 |
| 2010-07-10 | 00:07:00 | 23:52:00 | 23:45:00 | 11:59:30.0000 |
| 2010-07-11 | 00:07:00 | 23:22:00 | 23:15:00 | 11:44:30.0000 |
| 2010-07-12 | 01:37:00 | 23:52:00 | 22:15:00 | 12:44:30.0000 |
...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d72b/6)** demo

---

And in order to update `dayHoursHalf` column with respective values

```sql
UPDATE Table1
   SET dayHoursHalf = ADDTIME(sunrise, SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(dayHours) / 2))
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff9f1/1)** demo

Comment: Thank you, peterm. This is a beautiful piece of code and it seems close, but for some data points it doesn't seem to work:
    datePart    |  sunrise  |  sunset  |  dayHours  |  dayHoursHalf
    2010-08-19  |  05:07:00 |  21:22:00|  16:15:00  |  13:14:30
I don't know why it would work for some data points and not others, maybe there's a formatting problem in my original data?

Comment: You're very welcome. What is wrong with a row you showed? dayHours = '16:15:00'; dayHours / 2 = '08:07:30'; sunrise '05:07:00' + '08:07:30' = **13:14:30**. IMHO it's correct per your requirements.

Comment: Your code was more sophisticated than my brain, Peterm. I did not realize that you had calculated the actual midday value, and was looking for the number of hours halved, or the 8:07:30 hours as you show. Your answer is absolutely correct, and my apologies for being slow to grasp your answer, which was better than my question. In addition, I am finding your code useful for a different application, so many, many thanks to you.